# how would I go about taking a list of excel

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with one column with many entries. I would like to make a column to next to it that contains values of the first column that are an average of 16 entries of the first original column. Basically I just want to average every 16 values and make a new column that is 1/16 the length of the original. Is there any easy way to do this in excel? I have text files of this data that I am using to create the column of data so I could always write a python script to do this..but it seems like a hassle. Thanks!~ Andrew

Comment: Is this a one time thing or does it need to be easily repeatable?

Comment: I'll probably have to do it a few times. but this isn't something that will need to be done dozens or more times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that your column with values start at cell `A1` and goes down from there, then you can use the following formula in `B1`

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET($A$1,16*(ROW()-1),0,16))
```

From there on, select `B1` and pull down the bottom right corner to fill in the other values.

Comment: I did this a few years ago and was digging through my old files to try and find it.  That's pretty much exactly what I did.

Comment: ahh perfect! yes I figured there had to be a built in way to do what I wanted to do! though trying to google anything with the words "excel" and "average" gave me a bunch of basics about averaging but not what I was looking for. so thank you to the both of you!